# Strong Markov Property Brownian Motion for Non-Stopping Time

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, stopping-times

Let $B$ be a Brownian motion and let $\mathcal{F}^B$ be its natural filtration. Define the random variable
$$ \tau = \inf\{ t \ge 0 \mid B_t = \sup_{0 \le s \le 1} B_s \}.$$
Now, $\tau$ **is not** an $\mathcal{F}^B$ stopping time (as $\{\tau \le t\}$ is not $\mathcal{F}_t$ measurable). Consider the process
$$\hat{B} = (B_{t+\tau} - B_\tau)_{t \ge 0}.$$
My question is whether or not $\hat{B}$ is a Brownian motion (in its own filtration). Of course, if $\tau$ *were* a stopping time (in $\mathcal{F}^B$) then it is by the strong Markov property.

---

Ordinarily with a question like this, it would be fairly clear what the answer is, and then the challenge is proving it. I can't actually convince myself either way in this case! If someone could point me in the right direction (*please don't just give me the solutions, as I'd like to be able to work through it myself to get the most out of it!*) then I'd be most appreciative. :)

Comment: "This question has been flagged as: unclear what you're asking" FWIW, I strongly disagree (to tell the truth, I even find the flag *alarming*).

Comment: I got two downvotes in consecutive minutes on this and a BM hitting time question of mine. I guess it's just someone messing around. Such is life =P

Answer (score 4):

With probability $1$, $\tau<1$, and $\hat B$ is nonpositive on the whole interval $[0,1-\tau]$. As a Brownian motion takes positive and negative values arbitrarily close to $0$, $\hat B$ is not a Brownian motion.

Comment: Urgh, yeah, I thought it would be something easy, just couldn't see it for the life of me. Spent ages on it! Please note that I did **explicitly** ask for someone to point me in the right direction, and to not just be given the solution, which is what you've done. As such, I now know one piece of information, but haven't developed through getting there myself.